# Conditional Behavior With Free Monads

Tags: scala, free-monad, scala-cats

I'm following the tutorial here: http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html and trying to modify it to work with a cache in front of the key value store.  This is what I've come up with so far but I'm getting a compiler error with `valueGetOperation`.  I understand why I get the compile error, I just don't understand how to work around it.  What's the best practice for conditional behavior when using a free monad?

```
import cats.data.Coproduct
import cats.free.{Free, Inject}

object KvStore {
  sealed trait KvOp[A]
  case class Get[T](key: String) extends KvOp[Option[T]]
  case class Put[T](key: String, value: T) extends KvOp[Unit]
  case class Delete[T](key: String) extends KvOp[Unit]
}

object CacheStore {
  sealed trait CacheOp[A]
  case class Get[T](key: String) extends CacheOp[Option[T]]
  case class Put[T](key: String, value: T) extends CacheOp[Unit]
  case class Delete[T](key: String) extends CacheOp[Unit]
}

type WriteThruCache[A] = Coproduct[KvStore.KvOp, CacheStore.CacheOp, A]

class KvOps[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[KvStore.KvOp, F]) {
  import KvStore._
  def get[T](key: String): Free[F, Option[T]] = Free.inject[KvOp, F](Get(key))
  def put[T](key: String, value: T): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[KvOp, F](Put(key, value))
  def delete[T](key: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[KvOp, F](Delete(key))
}

object KvOps {
  implicit def kvOps[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[KvStore.KvOp, F]): KvOps[F] = new KvOps[F]
}

class CacheOps[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[CacheStore.CacheOp, F]) {
  import CacheStore._
  def get[T](key: String): Free[F, Option[T]] = Free.inject[CacheOp, F](Get(key))
  def put[T](key: String, value: T): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[CacheOp, F](Put(key, value))
  def delete[T](key: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[CacheOp, F](Delete(key))
}

object CacheOps {
  implicit def cacheOps[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[CacheStore.CacheOp, F]): CacheOps[F] = new CacheOps[F]
}

def valueWriteOperation[T](implicit Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]): ((String, T) => Free[WriteThruCache, Unit]) = {
  (key: String, value: T)  =>
    for {
      _ <- Kv.put(key, value)
      _ <- Cache.put(key, value)
    } yield ()
}

// This is where I'm stuck
// desired behavior: If the value isn't in the cache, load it from the kv store and put it in the cache
def valueGetOperation[T](implicit Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]): ((String) => Free[WriteThruCache, Option[T]]) = {
  (key: String) =>
    for {
      cacheOption <- Cache.get[T](key)
      kvOption <- Kv.get[T](key) if cacheOption.isEmpty // value withFilter is not a member of cats.free.Free[A$A39.this.WriteThruCache,Option[T]]
    } yield cacheOption.orElse(kvOption)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know in `for` comprehension, when you use `if` it is desugared by compiler to calling `withFilter` method, and if it's not accessible it falls back to `filter` method. If they are not implemented you will receive compiler error.

However you can simply use `if` `else`!

```
for {
  booleanValue <- myfreeAlbebra.checkCondidtion(arg1, arg2)
  valueToReturn <- if (booleanValue) {
    myfreeAlbebra.someValue
  } else {
    myfreeAlbebra.someOtherValue
  }
} yield valueToReturn
```

alternatively you can do something like:

```
for {
  booleanValue  <- myfreeAlbebra.checkCondidtion(arg1, arg2)
  valueToReturnOpt <- myfreeAlbebra.someValue
  fallbackValue <- myfreeAlbebra.someOtherValue
} yield valueToReturnOpt.getOrElse(fallbackValue)
```

The formar one will assign value to `valueToReturn` depending on `booleanValue`. As such only one branch will be interpreted. The later will evaluate both values and return one of them depending on whether or not `valueToReturnOpt` will be empty.

Personally I would try something like:

```
def valueGetOperation[T](implicit Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]): ((String) => Free[WriteThruCache, Option[T]]) = {
  (key: String) =>
    for {
      cacheOption <- Cache.get[T](key)
      returnedValue <- if (cacheOption.isEmpty) Cache.get[T](key) else Kv.get[T](key)
    } yield returnedValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more "functional" way than if/else but you're right it works.

Answer (score 0):

Following Mateusz' suggestions, this is what I came up with:

```
def withFallback[A[_], T](loadedValue: Option[T], fallback: => Free[A, Option[T]]): Free[A, Option[T]] = {
  if(loadedValue.isDefined) {
    Free.pure[A, Option[T]](loadedValue)
  } else {
    fallback
  }
}

def valueGetOperation[T](implicit Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]): ((String) => Free[WriteThruCache, Option[T]]) = {
  (key: String) =>
    for {
      cachedOption <- Cache.get[T](key)
      actualValue <- withFallback[WriteThruCache, T](cachedOption, fallback = Kv.get[T](key))
    } yield actualValue
}
```

If there's a standard construct to implement withFallback I'd be glad to know about it.

Comment: I'd define your `withFallback` as `loadedValue.fold(fallBack)(v => Free.pure(Some(v)))`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `OptionT#orElse`.

```
import cats.data.OptionT

type KV[A] = Free[WriteThruCache, A]

def valueGetOperation[T](
  implicit
  Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], 
  Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]
): String => KV[Option[T]] =
  key => OptionT[KV, T](Cache.get[T](key)).orElse(OptionT[KV, T](Kv.get[T](key))).value
```

Or `OptionT#orElseF` :

```
def valueGetOperation[T](
  implicit
  Kv: KvOps[WriteThruCache], 
  Cache: CacheOps[WriteThruCache]
): String => KV[Option[T]] = 
  key => OptionT[KV, T](Cache.get[T](key)).orElseF(Kv.get[T](key)).value
```

Note that with the `-Ypartial-unification` flag in Scala 2.12 you don't need the `KV` type alias and you can write `OptionT(...)` instead of `OptionT[KV, T](...)`.